# Android Call to local html page page not found

Tags: android, html, xamarin

So I'm developing a little app for a mobile device. In this app I also call a html page that should be located in my app folder. But the problem is I don't seem to get the correct path for android. It works perfectly on windows, but I can't get it to work on android.

Here is the code to get the path to the html page:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine("Avento.www", "ConsumerGoods");
path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "BulkAppointmentCreator");
path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Page.html");
path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path);
var url = "file://" + path;
```

When I go to this path on windows phone it works fine but as I said on android I get  page can not be found..

Anybody that can help?

Comment: 3 weeks later but still didn't get it to work. Anybody knows how to call a file from the installation folder?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a webview as this is a very good way to display html content inside an android app. Add the component to the desired layout xml:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp" />
```

Then add this to the matching activity or fragment:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/help.htm");
```

As you can see I've located all my html files in a specific folder which I created inside the android project.

```
myproject/assets/html/file.htm
```

Hope this helps.